# Iterating a Pandas dataframe over 'n' next rows

Tags: python, loops, pandas, iterator

I have this Pandas dataframe `df`:

```
station a_d direction
   a     0      0
   a     0      0
   a     1      0
   a     0      0
   a     1      0
   b     0      0
   b     1      0
   c     0      0
   c     1      0
   c     0      1
   c     1      1
   b     0      1
   b     1      1
   b     0      1
   b     1      1
   a     0      1
   a     1      1
   a     0      0
   a     1      0
```

I'd assign a value_id that increments when direction value change and refers only to the last pair of station value first it changes with different [0,1] a_d value. I can ignore the last (in this example the last two) dataframe row. In other words:

```
station a_d direction id_value
   a     0      0
   a     0      0
   a     1      0
   a     0      0        0
   a     1      0        0
   b     0      0        0
   b     1      0        0
   c     0      0        0
   c     1      0        0
   c     0      1        1
   c     1      1        1
   b     0      1         
   b     1      1        
   b     0      1        1
   b     1      1        1
   a     0      1        1
   a     1      1        1
   a     0      0
   a     1      0
```

Using `df.iterrows()` i write this script:

```
df['value_id'] = ""
value_id = 0
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
for i, row in row_iterator:
    if i == 0:
        continue
    elif (df.loc[i-1,'direction'] != df.loc [i,'direction']):
        value_id += 1
    for z in range(1,11):
        if i+z >= len(df)-1:
            break
        elif (df.loc[i+1,'a_d'] == df.loc [i,'a_d']):
            break
        elif (df.loc[i+1,'a_d'] != df.loc [i,'a_d']) and (df.loc [i+2,'station'] == df.loc [i,'station'] and (df.loc [i+2,'direction'] == df.loc [i,'direction'])):
            break
        else:
            df.loc[i,'value_id'] = value_id
```

It works but it's very slow. With a `10*10^6` rows dataframe I need a faster way. Any idea?

@user5402 code works well but I note that a `break` after the last `else` reduce computational time also:

```
df['value_id'] = ""
value_id = 0
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
for i, row in row_iterator:
    if i == 0:
        continue
    elif (df.loc[i-1,'direction'] != df.loc [i,'direction']):
        value_id += 1
    for z in range(1,11):
        if i+z >= len(df)-1:
            break
        elif (df.loc[i+1,'a_d'] == df.loc [i,'a_d']):
            break
        elif (df.loc[i+1,'a_d'] != df.loc [i,'a_d']) and (df.loc [i+2,'station'] == df.loc [i,'station'] and (df.loc [i+2,'direction'] == df.loc [i,'direction'])):
            break
        else:
            df.loc[i,'value_id'] = value_id
            break
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't seem to produce that output.

Comment: I mean that I get `['', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', 1, 1, '', '', 1, 1, '', '']` as the `value_id` column, which doesn't match your output's `id_value` column.

Comment: You are not effectively using `z` in the inner for loop - in fact, it can be totally eliminated. Don't you want to use `df.loc[i+z,...` somewhere in that loop?

Comment: @DSM I corrected the code

Comment: @user5402 I use `z`. It increments when the i+z row doesn't satisfy the `if` condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not effectively using `z` in the inner for loop. You never access the `i+z`-th row. You access the i-th row and the `i+1`-th row and the `i+2`-th row, but never the `i+z`-th row.

You can replace that inner for loop with:

```
  if i+1 > len(df)-1:
    pass
  elif (df.loc[i+1,'a_d'] == df.loc [i,'a_d']):
    pass
  elif (df.loc [i+2,'station'] == df.loc [i,'station'] and (df.loc [i+2,'direction'] == df.loc [i,'direction'])):
    pass
  else:
    df.loc[i,'value_id'] = value_id
```

Note that I also slightly optimized the second `elif` because at that point you already know `df.loc[i+1,'a_d']` does not equal `df.loc [i,'a_d']`.

Not having to loop over `z` will save a lot of time.

Comment: Yes it works, but I realize that a `break` after the last `else` in the inner for loop makes the script as fast as the script without for cycle

Comment: You don't need the line `for z in range(1,11)` in your code at all. I bet you needed to add the `break` statement because you still have the `for z ...` line in your code. Just get rid of it and reindent the loop body to the left one level.

Comment: Maybe you don't understand my comment. I say that your proposed solution takes the same time of my that with `break` after the last `else`. I just edit my post. Are you agree?

Comment: Ok - I see what you are saying now.